# Execution time of Stanford CoreNLP on other languages

Tags: stanford-nlp

I need to extract sentences, tokens, pos tags and lemma from English and German text of a big corpora. So, I used the Stanford CoreNLP tool. Its output is perfect. However, the problem is the time complexity. The English one executes quickly but the German model takes a long time to annotate the text. I initialize the models with these codes:

```
// To initialize English model
propsEN = new Properties();
propsEN.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma");
propsEN.setProperty("tokenize.language", "en");
corenlpEN = new StanfordCoreNLP(propsEN);


// To initialize German model
propsDE = new Properties();
propsDE.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma");
propsDE.setProperty("tokenize.language", "de");
corenlpDE = new StanfordCoreNLP(propsDE);
```

To represent the difference in execution times, I computed the length of each text and the time each model takes to run on the text. In order to calculate the execution time, I used System.currentTimeMillis() instruction:

## Executing the Stanford CoreNLP model on English Text:

> English text length=1587   --- Elapse time=57
>
> English text length=15906 --- Elapse time=160
>
> English text length=44286 --- Elapse time=3287
>
> English text length=19814 --- Elapse time=1809
>
> English text length=1427  --- Elapse time=166
>
> English text length=56787 --- Elapse time=2374

## Executing the Stanford CoreNLP model on German Text:

> German text length=979 --- Elapse time=401
>
> German text length=22039  ---  Elapse time=15285
>
> German text length=30632  --- Elapse time=21659
>
> German text length=42019  --- Elapse time=21767
>
> German text length=2944  --- Elapse time=2005
>
> German text length=76248 --- Elapse time=48857

Why does German model take several times? Have I made any mistake? Is there any solution to solve the problem?

Any information about this topic is appreciated.

Comment: @Jon Gauthier : Could you please answer this question

Comment: @ Sebastian Schuster  : Could you please answer this question

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp  : Could you please answer this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will help, but you're not using the German part of speech tagger.  You can set that with the `pos.model` property.

Here is a list of options (make sure you have the German models jar):

```
edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/german/german-fast.tagger
edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/german/german-hgc.tagger
edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/german/german-fast-caseless.tagger
edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/german/german-ud.tagger
```

Also there is no `lemma` for German.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was completely helpful. The execution time decreased dramatically.

Comment: What about Spanish language? Is it has a fast pos tagger and lemmatizer model?

Comment: StanfordNLPHelp :

Comment: Unfortunately there is no faster model for Spanish.